# Row reduction and the characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can you row reduce the matrix before computing $\det(\lambda I-A)$? Will this still give an equivalent characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Similarity transformations preserve the characteristic polynomial of a matrix, but elementary row operations alone do not.

Comment: Are you wanting to row-reduce $A$ or $\lambda I-A$?

Comment: Given that not all operations used in row reduction (like scaling a row by a constant multiple - if you scaled *every* row, then you'd be scaling the characteristic polynomial as well) preserve the characteristic polynomial, I'd be doubtful.

Comment: @hardmath do you mean that some elementary row operations will preserve the characteristic polynomial but not all? Which ones should I stay away from?

Comment: While a subset of elementary row operations can be identified that preserve the determinant (and thus can be applied to $\lambda I - A$ to compute its polynomial determinant), scarcely any of the elementary row operations alone preserve the characteristic polynomial of $A$.  I'll give some examples.

Comment: Try for yourself.  Let $A=2I$.  More generally, the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are elementary symmetric functions evaluated at the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A typical presentation of [elementary row operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Operations) sets out three kinds:

(1) Multiply a row by a nonzero scalar.

(2) Add a multiple of one row to another.

(3) Swap two rows.

The effects on the determinant of a (square) matrix when these are applied are easily determined.  (1) multiplies the determinant by the same scalar used to multiply the row.  (2) leaves the determinant unchanged.  (3) changes the sign of the determinant.

However even if the cumulative effects of a series of row operations were contrived to leave the determinant of $A$ unchanged, this does not imply that the characteristic polynomial is preserved.  For the characteristic polynomial to remain unchanged, we would need all the elementary symmetric invariants of characteristic roots (the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, effectively) to stay the same.

For simplicity let's consider only the trace of $A$, the sum of characteristic roots, which determines the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$, which is also the sum of the diagonal entries of $A$.  Operation (1) adds $(r-1)a_{ii}$ to the trace, when the *i*th row is multiplied by $r$.  Operation (2) adds $r a_{ij}$ to the trace, when $r$ times the *i*th row is added to the *j*th row.  Operation (3) adds $a_{ij}+a_{ji}-a_{ii}-a_{jj}$ to the trace when the *i*th and *j*th rows are swapped.  All these are fairly unpredicatable effects on the trace, and hence on the characteristic polynomial.

Considering the case of a $2\times 2$ matrix, we see that the reduced row-echelon form of a matrix $A$ is has characteristic polynomial either $\lambda^2$, $\lambda(\lambda-1)$, or $(\lambda-1)^2$.  Reconstructing even the characteristic polynomial of $A$ from the characteristic polynomial of its reduced row-echelon form seems unwieldy.

On the other hand it does make sense to consider computing $\det(\lambda I - A)$ by applying elementary row operations to row reduce $\lambda I - A$.  However since the matrix entries are polynomials, say from $\mathbb{R}[\lambda]$, the ring operations are not as easy to carry out as in the case of row reducing real matrix $A$.

For example consider the matrix $A$ and its reduced row echelon form $R$:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \; R = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

The characteristic polynomial for $A$ is $\lambda^2 - 1$, while the characteristic polynomial for $R$ is $(\lambda - 1)^2$.  Only a single elementary row operation, swapping the two rows, was required to change $A$ into $R$.

However the polynomial matrix:

$$ \lambda I - A = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & -1 \\ -1 & \lambda \end{pmatrix} $$

may be reduced by a sequence of three elementary row operations (one of each kind!) to upper triangular form:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\lambda \\ 0 & \lambda^2 - 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

whose determinant is evidently $\lambda^2 - 1$.  Thus elementary row operations applied to $\lambda I - A$ can provide us the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't row reduce in advance. You will get a different characteristic polynomial if you do that.
For example,matrix A=$\left[
\begin{array} {lcr}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & 3 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right] $ has a characteristic polynomial (2-$\lambda$)(1-$\lambda$)$^2$ 
But the reduced matrix A'= $\left[
\begin{array} {lcr}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]$ has a different characteristic polynomial (2-$\lambda$)(1+$\lambda$) $^2$